# How do I correctly use fetch assets with a local identifier?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to figure out how to get an array of identifiers and put them in a collection view programmatically. Correct me if I am wrong but, I believe the best way to do this is by using `PHAsset.fetchAssets`. At most I anticipate the users fetching 10 images (avg. 3-4) so I do not think the process would be very resource intensive. I am testing the code below with a specific array of identifiers. In the cellForItemAt function on the line where I assign the asset I get an error message. See the comment above that line. I have seen similar issues on SO but I have not been able to apply anything that I found. What am I doing wrong?

```
var identifier: [String] = ["83BDF9C0-E1FB-4F68-9F2C-99649A67E218/L0/001", "18D08CEC-4075-4488-BFD1-E9403B214356/L0/001", "74257416-6D9C-48B2-9CE0-C23B56CB4171/L0/001", "2EA7CACE-9B9B-4FC9-ABC5-03BCE2BDAA2A/L0/001", "46A4CD2B-4FEB-4BBE-86DC-B79ED49BC300/L0/001", "E4290EB0-2B16-46AE-9B98-83379F6128F3/L0/001", "7C0B36FF-320D-4083-92E4-5A1F464FFFB1/L0/001", "DEE1414C-2B92-4147-8C3C-A1775FB324AD/L0/001"]
    
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    
    var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        myCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        myCollectionView.register(ImageEditCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        myCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageEditCell
        cell.representedAssetIdentifier = identifier[0]
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
        
        // LINE BELOW PRODUCES ERROR: Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected element type 'Array<String>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'String')
        let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [identifier], options: .none).firstObject
        
        imgManager.requestImage(for: asset!, targetSize: CGSize(width:120, height: 120),
                                contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                options: requestOptions,
                                resultHandler: { result, info in
                                    if cell.representedAssetIdentifier == self.identifier {
                                        cell.imageview.image = result
                                    }
                                })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. I realized i was not correctly converting the identifier to a UIImage so even if I had fixed the error in the OP it still would not work because of numerous others that would have come up with that solution. Below is the solution i got to work:

```
    var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var imageViews = [UIImageView]()
    var identifier = [
        "83BDF9C0-E1FB-4F68-9F2C-99649A67E218/L0/001",
        "18D08CEC-4075-4488-BFD1-E9403B214356/L0/001",
        "74257416-6D9C-48B2-9CE0-C23B56CB4171/L0/001",
        "2EA7CACE-9B9B-4FC9-ABC5-03BCE2BDAA2A/L0/001",
        "46A4CD2B-4FEB-4BBE-86DC-B79ED49BC300/L0/001",
        "E4290EB0-2B16-46AE-9B98-83379F6128F3/L0/001",
        "7C0B36FF-320D-4083-92E4-5A1F464FFFB1/L0/001",
        "DEE1414C-2B92-4147-8C3C-A1775FB324AD/L0/001"
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        myCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        myCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        myCollectionView.register(CollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return identifier.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        
        let options = PHFetchOptions()
        let results = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: identifier, options: options)
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        results.enumerateObjects { (thisAsset, _, _) in
            manager.requestImage(for: thisAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(thisImage, _) in
                self.imageViews.append(UIImageView(image: thisImage))
            })
        }
        let image = imageViews[indexPath.item]
        cell.imageView.image = image.image
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Why did you create an PHFetchOptions object for the fetchAssets function parameter, you could have passed nil as a value right?

Answer (score 2):

Here I've moved fetch function to viewDidLoad in order to prevent other errors and also I am not sure what you are fetching whether it is an array with images(if so then by putting .firstObject you are fetching a single image which may cause an error)

```
var identifier: [String] = ["83BDF9C0-E1FB-4F68-9F2C-99649A67E218/L0/001", "18D08CEC-4075-4488-BFD1-E9403B214356/L0/001", "74257416-6D9C-48B2-9CE0-C23B56CB4171/L0/001", "2EA7CACE-9B9B-4FC9-ABC5-03BCE2BDAA2A/L0/001", "46A4CD2B-4FEB-4BBE-86DC-B79ED49BC300/L0/001", "E4290EB0-2B16-46AE-9B98-83379F6128F3/L0/001", "7C0B36FF-320D-4083-92E4-5A1F464FFFB1/L0/001", "DEE1414C-2B92-4147-8C3C-A1775FB324AD/L0/001"]
    
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    
    var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        myCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        myCollectionView.register(ImageEditCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        myCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [identifier], options: .none)

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageEditCell
        cell.representedAssetIdentifier = identifier[indexPath.row]
       
        imgManager.requestImage(for: asset!, targetSize: CGSize(width:120, height: 120),
                                contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                options: requestOptions,
                                resultHandler: { result, info in
                                    if cell.representedAssetIdentifier == self.identifier {
                                        cell.imageview.image = result
                                    }
                                })
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think I understand what you are suggesting but perhaps you can provide an example. Just copy my code into the answer box and make the edit it as you are suggesting, because as you eluded to this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check it and let me know if it fixed an issue